# Navigating back and forward at once in path C#

Tags: c#, path

I have to come back 5 folders in path then I need to enter 3 folders further and check if file exist.

Lets imagine two paths:

```
1) C:\a\b\c\d\e\f\g\

2) C:\a\2\3\4\5\test.xml
```

Then my program right now is on the first path.
I need to check if file test.xml (on the second path) exists.

For that I know method File.Exists(path), however I have problems with path.
I am able to come back until folder a and check if the file is there.
For example to check if the file on the path exists:

```
3) C:\a\test2.xml
```

I may use:

```
File.Exists(@".\.\.\.\.\.\" + @"test2.xml");
```

But nevertheless my attempts to navigate to second path ( 2) ) and check if this file exists I can not to that. May anyone help me with that ? Thanks in advance. Regards.

Comment: Can you please show some code of what you've done? It's a little unclear what exactly is your problem. You may be looking for [`Path.GetDirectoryName()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getdirectoryname%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Actually there is no code around this process. I want to make if() which is entered if the file exists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

. refers to the current directory
.. refers to the directory one level above the current

In your example:

```
..\..\..\..\..\..\2\3\4\5\test.xml
```

This moves up to the a directory then traverses down to 5 where your file resides.

Something that might be helpful to test your path and ensure you are where you think you are is this:

```
string currentPath = Path.GetFullPath(relativePath);
```

And then check the value of currentPath, if it winds up somewhere you didn't expect you can debug your path traversal rather than your code.

Comment: Now I have been debugging this with Path.Combine and Path.GetFullName methods. Thank you for time and regards :)

Answer (score 2):

You just need to use `..` to signify a parent directory.

Try:

```
File.Exists(@"..\..\..\..\..\..\" + @"test2.xml");
```

Comment: Using immediate Window:

File.Exists(Path.Combine(@"..\..\..\..\.." + @"\CoreCalc.dll"));
gives me false while File.Exists(Path.Combine(@".\.\.\.\." + @"\CoreCalc.dll")); gives me true.

Anyway thank you for reply :)

Comment: @jankowalski: Look at what `Path.Combine` returns.  You're actually just getting `\CoreCalc.dll`.

Comment: This code is going to use the directory the executable is running in to find the path. You may need to assume it is running in bin/Debug so go up an additional two directories.

Comment: You was right Saqib, actually I had another file with same name and extension that is why I got true. Of course .. is coming back in path. My final product is working on different location than debug file. Now I have been debugging this with Path.Combine and Path.GetFullName methods. Thank you for time and regards :)